# react-native, closure variable causes action to fail

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I have a simple http call with a success callback, however when I try to return on the original parameters, react return an un handled promise rejection error, which causes my dispatch to fail:

```
export function deleteFriendRequest(userId) {
  return dispatch => {
    // dispatch(deleteFriendRequestSuccess({}, userId))
    request.del({dispatch, path: `/friends/${userId}`, body: {}, deleteFriendRequestSuccess, deleteFriendRequestFailure, initialData: userId})
  }
}

function deleteFriendRequestSuccess(payload, initialData) {
  console.log('delete friend request success', payload, userId) // this works I get the correct user id
  return {
    type: FRIENDS_DELETE_FRIEND_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
    payload: {sentId: initialData},
  }
}

function deleteFriendRequestFailure(error) {
  return {
    type: FRIENDS_DELETE_FRIEND_REQUEST_FAILURE,
    error,
  }
}

export function del({dispatch, path, body, success, failure, initialData}) {
  const url = API_URL + path
  const token = store.getState().auth.token

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'AccessToken': token && token.token ? token.token : null,
      'deviceUID': DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.status < 200 || response.status > 299) {
        throw ({errorMessage: 'Invalid response'}, response)
      } else {
        return response
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(checkForResponseError)
    .then(json => {
      dispatch(success(json, initialData))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(failure(err))
    })
}
```

causes:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
failure is not a function
TypeError: failure is not a function
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:84194:10
    at tryCallOne (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:29539:8)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:29625:9
    at JSTimersExecution.callbacks.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:12854:13)
    at Object.callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:12686:1)
    at Object.callImmediatesPass (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:12744:19)
    at Object.callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:12759:25)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:11613:43
    at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:11518:1)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true:11613:1)
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an options object that you then destructure in the function header. Since you pass it under a different name, the `failure` var is not assigned so when you call the `failure` function in the `catch` of the promise, it fails. This makes the result of the `catch` call, which is also a promise, fail with that error. Since you do nothing with the result of the`catch` call, you get an unhandled promise rejection notice.

Your `success` function isn't passed correctly either, which is probably what causes the `catch` to be reached on the first place.

Your function should look like this:

```
export function deleteFriendRequest(userId) {
  return dispatch => {
    // dispatch(deleteFriendRequestSuccess({}, userId))
    request.del({
      dispatch,
      path: `/friends/${userId}`,
      body: {},
      success: deleteFriendRequestSuccess,
      failure: deleteFriendRequestFailure,
      initialData: userId
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: ah, sorry, I did not add the deleteFriendRequestFailure function in the snippet above, it was late and I was tired, it is defined, yet the same error is thrown, I'll edit the answer to include it

Comment: Did the updated answer help you solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the solution. If not, let me know what's wrong, so I can fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks, I did not properly update the code, while I eventually ended up with the exact same code as yours (but I did not take a look at your updated answer until now), I do not understand why passing an object causes the params to remain available in the closure, any clarification would be greatly appreciated.